# How do I test if my motherboard is failing using Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, memory, motherboard

I've been having strange segfaults happen randomly to firefox, qsynth, and totem. Mainly firefox.

I've tested my hard drives with smartctl and dd, and tested my ram with memtest, but how do I test my motherboard?

Running Ubuntu 12.04.

I want to note as well that even if hardware failure isn't the cause of the segfaults, I would still like to be able to run some commands in Linux and test my motherboard. My overall goal here is to gain that piece of knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To check your motherboard health in Linux you can use  the below command as a root user.

```
sudo dmidecode |grep -B 2 Stat
```

It will give the status of all peripheral working status.

For example:

```
[root@Ubuntu ~]# dmidecode |grep -B 2 Stat
Serial Number: .....
Asset Tag:
Boot-up State: Safe
Power Supply State: Safe
Thermal State: Safe
Security Status: None
--
Max Speed: 5200 MHz
Current Speed: 2400 MHz
Status: Populated, Enabled
--
On Board Device Information
Type: Ethernet
Status: Enabled
--
On Board Device Information
Type: Sound
Status: Enabled
--
On Board Device Information
Type: Other
Status: Enabled
--
Access Method: Memory-mapped physical 32-bit address
Access Address: 0xFFF81000
Status: Valid, Not Full
--
Handle 0x1800, DMI type 24, 5 bytes.
Hardware Security
Power-On Password Status: Enabled
Keyboard Password Status: Not Implemented
Administrator Password Status: Enabled
Front Panel Reset Status: Not Implemented
--
Cooling Device
Type: Fan
Status: OK
--
Cooling Device
Type: Fan
Status: OK
--
Cooling Device
Type: Fan
Status: OK
--
Handle 0x2000, DMI type 32, 11 bytes.
System Boot Information
Status: No errors detected
```

Comment: @catpants welcome friend.